# Input from html to mysql using flask; only accepts single character inputs

Tags: html, mysql, flask

So I am using Flask to pass an input from html to a mysql db. However it only works for single characters ie can only input "5" and "a", however it cannot input "55" or "at". Here is my code.

```
__init__.py :
@app.route('/statistics',methods=['GET','POST'])
def statsinput():
        if request.method=='GET':
                return render_template("statsinput.html")
        else:
                first_name=(request.form['fname'])
                c, conn = connection()
                query="INSERT INTO test VALUES(%s)"
                c.execute(query,first_name)
                conn.commit()
                return ('working')

statsinput.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
    <form method="POST">
      First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

Here is the description for my mysql table:
mysql> DESCRIBE test;
 +--------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ticker | char(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert correctly in the query string.

```
query="INSERT INTO test VALUES({})".format(first_name)
c.execute(query)
```

Comment: @GuyMowbray What is doesn't work. This will work sure.

Comment: unfortunately not, dont know whats wrong with it; ive tried to follow instructions from this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42662502/getting-the-input-from-html-form-and-storing-it-in-mysql-through-flask)